# How do I manage Web Site Analytics of a Load-Balanced Web Site?

Tags: cloud, web-analytics, rackspace

I'm using Rackspace Cloud Servers to power my Web site. One of the cool features is that I can clone servers and load-balance them to enhance performance when traffic spikes.

However, I'm concerned how I'm going to manage the Web Analytics being that these are now going to be individual servers.

Is there any solution out there that makes doing this easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics should work exactly the same regardless of which backend node in your cluster is serving the content, since the tracking actually happens at the google side.  Could always go with that.

Comment: Thanks. I found this [answer](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=4136ecbd7ed84775&hl=en) online which I believes deals with the question also.